# Do you know of any OpenSSH libraries for Windows?

Tags: .net, windows, openssh

I'd like to incorporate OpenSSH support into a Windows application and I am looking for a library (preferably .Net or something easily integrated into .Net) that can provide this functionality.  I'm more interested in ssh client software than server software, but both functions would be even better.

**Edit**: I'd prefer a free and open source solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeProject provides a good **free** option with [sharpSsh](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharpssh.aspx)

Comment: Did I mention sharpSsh is free?

Comment: ++ for freeness although code project always smells funny to me.

Comment: Very true, sometimes with open source you get what you pay for, but if you're just looking for ideas it's a great place to start.

Comment: Apparently it's a port of JSch for Java, which gives me a little more confidence in it.
http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx

Comment: I ended up going with sharpSSH and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [WeOnlyDo](http://www.weonlydo.net/). They have some nice .NET SSH components like [wodSSH.Net](http://www.weonlydo.com/index.asp?showform=SSH.NET) for $199.

Also, [nSoftware](http://www.nsoftware.com/) has some great networking components like [IP*Works SSH .Net edition](http://www.nsoftware.com/order/ssh.aspx) for $599.

If you go with nSoftware their best value is the [red carpet subscription](http://www.nsoftware.com/subscriptions/default.aspx). This is what we have. It starts at $1499 per developer.

(Prices as of 3/4/09)

Comment: -2 trying to sell stuff here,
+1 listing the prices,
+1 being exactly on point with the question.

Don't know what to think...

Comment: Not selling anything. I don't have any ties to either company, except that I have used their products.

There were several down votes for this answer, but I don't understand what is inherently wrong with recommending a commercial solution.

When I have the need for a library I look at all options.

Comment: I don't mind that a non-free solution was offered, I just prefer to know prices in the answer. I'm the one that initially added the pricing information.

Comment: I understand adding the pricing info. That was a good addition. I was just talking about Bill K's comment about -2 for trying to sell stuff here.

Comment: Windows/.NET is a commercial, closed-source software platform on a commercial, closed-source OS. In that context, I don't see why all the sudden being commercial and closed-source becomes bad when it comes to a third-party add-on library. And those prices are totally reasonable when you compare what it costs a company to develop and maintain a component like that. If the answer were "Visual Studio" or "Excel", I doubt anyone would bat an eye.

Answer (score 1):

Theres also [SSH Factory for .NET](http://www.jscape.com/sshfactorydotnet/) and [Granados](http://granados.sourceforge.net/) for .NET at $599.

(prices as of 3/5/09)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming by the way you phrased your question, it would indicate that you are mainly interested in the SSH/SSH2 functionality...

How does this sound:

[Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) - a module for python that implements the SSH2 protocol

requires [`pycrypto`](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) --

- `pycrypto` Windows binaries can be found [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto)
- [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=IronPython) implementation of `pycrypto` apparent available in [`FePy`](http://fepy.sourceforge.net/). see [here](http://lists.ironpython.com/pipermail/users-ironpython.com/2008-July/007565.html) and [here](http://fepy.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fepy/trunk/fepy/cipher.py?view=log)

Comment: BTW, here is a article reprint available from a magazine showing how powerful paramiko can be and how simple it is to use:  http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/

Comment: Sounds quite good.  Although I specified .Net this will be good to know for future development.

Comment: I think you'd be able to integrate the IronPython version directly with .Net, since IronPython it is CLI-based implementation of Python...

Answer (score 1):

you can try our [Rebex SSH Pack](http://www.rebex.net/ssh-pack/) which includes:

- SSH core client library compatible with OpenSSH
- SSH Shell with terminal emulator component
- SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) client component
- SCP client component

You can download the trial at http://www.rebex.net/ssh-pack/download.aspx